# php Json_decode correct way to get individual data

Tags: php, jquery, json

```
$json=json_encode($_POST['myData']);
$decoded = json_decode($json,true); 
if (is_array($decoded)) {
    foreach ($decoded as $value) {
        echo $value["name"] . "=" . $value["value"];
    }
}
```

I have separate values for each and every field and i want separate values to store in database..

Post is in this way:

```
myData[0][name]  =  name
myData[0][value] =  Yaseen
myData[1][name]  =  age
myData[1][value] =  22
myData[2][name]  =  gender
myData[2][value] =  male
myData[3][name]  =  skills
myData[3][value] =  Php
myData[4][name]  =  note
myData[4][value] =  sad
Please help...Thanks
```

var_dump() result:

```
    <br/>
     array(1) { <br/>
      ["myData"]=><br/>
      array(5) {<br/>
      [0]=><br/>
      array(2) {<br/>
      ["name"]=><br/>
      string(4) "name"<br/>
      ["value"]=><br/>
      string(6) "xyz"<br/>
     }<br/>
    [1]=><br/>
     array(2) {<br/>
      ["name"]=><br/>
      string(3) "age"<br/>
      ["value"]=><br/>
      string(2) "22"<br/>
    }<br/>
    [2]=><br/><br/>
    array(2) {<br/>
      ["name"]=><br/>
      string(6) "gender"<br/>
      ["value"]=><br/>
      string(4) "male"<br/>
    }<br/>
    [3]=><br/>
    array(2) {<br/>
      ["name"]=><br/>
      string(6) "skills"<br/><br/>
      ["value"]=><br/>
      string(3) "Php"<br/>
    }<br/>
    [4]=><br/>
    array(2) {<br/>
      ["name"]=><br/>
      string(4) "note"<br/>
      ["value"]=><br/>
      string(6) "asdasd"<br/>
    }<br/>
  }<br/>
}<br/>
```

Comment: Response is like this name=xyzage=22gender=maleskills=Phpnote=asdasd
But i dont want to be like this

Comment: Why you encode and after decode? `$_POST['myData']` already array. `var_dump($_POST['myData']);`

Comment: yes its already an array so how should i get the individual value

Comment: I guess your datas under `myData[]` so you can get with `echo $_POST['myData']['gender'];`

Comment: Its showing the notice as  Undefined index: gender

Comment: Could you paste to question `var_dump($_POST);` result, please.

Comment: Please check the var dump result

Comment: Your post so complex. You can access but can build array more simple. Try `echo $_POST['myData'][0][value];`, `echo $_POST['myData'][1][value];` etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$json=json_encode($_POST['myData']);
$decoded = json_decode($json,true); 

if (is_array($decoded)) {
  for($i = 0; $i <= count($decoded); $i++) {
        echo $decoded[$i]["name"];

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok i am using the foreach loop as :
foreach($decoded as $value){
   echo $weight = $value['value'];    
}
which gives the values as : 
xyz20malePhptesting which are actually 5 separate values..So inned it as xyz,20,male,Php,testing to store in database ..How do i do that??